# why my browser fingerprint result is always same?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, hash, fingerprintjs2

```
declare var Fingerprint2: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Hello`,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
      console.log(result); // Device fingerprint as a hash value
      console.log(components); // an array of FP components
    });
  }
}
```

Browser fingerprint is information collected about a remote device for the purpose of identification. In Angular 4, I'm getting result as a hash value to identify the remote system.

But the problem is always getting same result(hash value) when accessing the web application with different users credentials and from the same system/browser(Using Chrome) .

Is there any way to get unique result (hash value) to identify the browser information for the different user from the same Browser or always browser will return same result(hash value) from the same Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run fingerprinting directly on or after page load. Rather, delay it for a few milliseconds with setTimeout or requestIdleCallback to ensure consistent fingerprints.

Comment: I need unique fingerprint not a consistent fingerprint